# AngularJS, a number gets added to a string after a click event

Tags: angularjs

Here is the beginning of my function:

```
    function get_argumentation(type,id,boxClass, argumentcontent){
        type = type || 'argumentation';
        id = id || 0;
        boxClass = boxClass || 2;
        argumentcontent = argumentcontent || 0;

        alert(type); <== returns 'argument1'
```

Here, the function gets called in the view:

```
 ng-click="nextargumentation('argument',211, 4, 0)"
```

The alert `alert(type)` returns `'argument1'` instead of just `'argument'`. Can anyone see the problem?

EDIT:

Daniel pointed out the problem: I used the wrong function.

Comment: is the method `get_argumentation` or `nextargumentation`?

Comment: @Daniel You're right, the argument was wrong. Thanks. How embarrassing